# Android сохранение во временной памяти

Tags: android, memory

При запуске приложения, пользователь получает нужные ему данные которые должны действовать во время работы приложения, т.е. к примеру,пользователь зашел, получил данные, вышел и они должны удалиться. 
Главная цель чтоб доступ к этим данным был из любого активити.
Каким образом можно этого добиться ? 
Если хранить в бд или в sharedPrefrencess то надо отслеживать когда приложение будет выключено. Но как я понимаю этого отследить не возможно ибо пользователь может крашнуть приложение либо его просто закрыть и это не отследить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все верно описал @VAndrJ, с одной поправкой: в Android естественным синглтоном является объект типа `Application` - заведите свой класс `Application` и держите в нем свои данные.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private int myData;

    public int getMyData() { return myData; }
    public void setMyData(int myData) {this.myData=myData; }
}
```

Далее в любом `Activity`:

```
MyApplication myApplication=(MyApplication )this.getApplication();
Log.i("TAG", "myData="+myApplication.getMyData());
```

Не забудьте продекларировать `MyApplication` в манифесте.

Answer (score 4):

Ну один из самых простых вариантов для описанного случая - паттерн `singleton`.

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   private ClassicSingleton() {}

   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Далее добавляете необходимые поля, в которых будете хранить данные и обращаетесь к ним через `ClassicSingleton.getInstance().имяПоля/геттер/сеттер` (как задумаете)